# Disconnect a remote session from a remote session

Tags: remote-desktop, remote, remote-access, remote-control, session

I have a remote server running at my university (Windows 8 Enterprise).
I'm going to have 10 different people/testers run some tests on that server, they will not run the tests simultaneously but rather 1 tester at a time while I supervise and assist them.
Now obviously I don't want to give them direct access to the server.
Instead I want to give them temporary access and have the ability to terminate their session if they would start doing something unexpected, like running through various directories or delete system files.

How can I set up an environment where I can do this?
What software do I use?

Comment: Can't be done with that version of Windows, or any version, but that specfic version wont allow 10 simultaneously connected users

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry if I was unclear, I've edited my question now.
To clarify, I'll have 10 different users/strangers connected to the server but not at the same time.
At any given time only 1 tester and I will be connected to the server. I wish to elevate my access somehow or limit their access so I can terminate their session if needed, but more importantly I want to know how I can enable concurrent connections. (I've googled this and stumbled upon TeamViewer, VNC and modifications of termsrv.dll, I'd rather apply a solution that is least intrusive and that allows a connection for my testers...

Comment: ... without additional setup (so I don't want to tell people to install this and that software, I want to make it as easy as possible for them to connect, while retaining the possibility of terminating their session if needed).

Comment: Still not possible.  You won't be able to know what they are doing while they are logged into a user account

Comment: Why don't you run a VM -> prepare the machine how you want it to start (prior to testing) -> snapshot the VM -> let the testing begin -> after each test revert the VM so that all changes are lost...

Comment: I'm looking into using TeamViewer now, so I can be connected using Windows RDP and the tester can be connected via TeamViewer.
VM is probably the easiest way to go about but due to my inexperience with VMs (idk how to set them up and what software to use) and the fact that my project is in its final stage I'll put the VM route aside for now.
Let's assume that it doesn't work out using TeamViewer or VNC though, do you have any good resources, tutorials, websites or tips regarding setting up a VM? And in my case I would only need a VM that can run TeamCity (Win8 preferably) and accept remote con

Comment: Ok, so I'm done with TeamViewer and it works out for my needs.
You can enable VoIP during a TeamViewer session so that's a nice feature I will use. I'm a bit disappointed by the fact that I can't record the session as a host, instead I'll have to connect to the session from another PC to record the session. It's a bit of a hassle but it will have to do, hopefully the TeamViewer devs enable hosts to record sessions in future versions of TeamViewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TeamViewer works for this and it is what I'll be using.
Please view the comment section below the question for further information.